# How to make a cutout in a Fizik Arione?

Tags: saddle

**My goal** -- I would like to make a cutout in Fizik Arione.

My question is **addressed to** people who tried to make a cutout by themselves.

My very simple question **is** -- how to do a cutout in Arione by yourself, and not destroy the saddle?

---

Please answer **if and only if** you tried to customize Arione by yourself.

Comment: What makes you think the Arione with a cutout, which is the same as the Versus shape wise, would be any better than the Versus, if you managed to cut a hole in it without destroying it? Which model of Arione do you have?

Comment: Macias, this site is intended for questions you actually need an answer to. You are complaining about a product which you think should be designed better, but the fact is, it's a product which works for a lot of people as is. There are a ton of other saddles with cutouts that you could choose. If you don't own the Arione, you aren't locked in to using it, as you implied in your question. So find a saddle that works for you, rather than buying a saddle you aren't happy with, and trying to modify it. It makes no sense.

Comment: I think you should really do it if you think this is the right thing to do. But I think this is not a proper thing to ask here, because there would be impossible to provide a closed answer to this distorted problem.

Comment: Really?  How many people add cutouts to their saddle?  I've never seen anyone do it.  So first you've got to find someone who has done something as stupid as you're suggesting, then you have to hope he chose the same saddle.  I don't think you're going to find anyone.

Answer (score 1):

First, an answer.  If you try to modify the Arione, it very much does matter which model you have. If the base of the saddle is composite, then you could make a cut out. But it is unlikely to last very long. I expect that the filler materials, the gel, the foams will simply move out of place out of your new cutout.

If it uses the woven base, the one that is soft material like kevlar, then you won't be able to make the cutout without damaging it at all, IMHO.

You are complaining about a product which you think should be designed better, but the fact is, it's a product which works for a lot of people as is. There are a ton of other saddles with cutouts that you could choose. If you don't own the Arione, you aren't locked in to using it, as you implied in your question. So find a saddle that works for you, rather than buying a saddle you aren't happy with, and trying to modify it. It makes no sense.

Comment: Sometimes the right answer is that something shouldn't be done and that you should try other options. As for implying you needed to ride this saddle, you said you were stuck with it. That made the choice of phrase about "I didn't buy it" seem like it was a gift. If it wasn't intentional, that's fine. But that's what I got out of it. I wasn't trying to start a fight. I was giving you information.  Your additional comments regarding your apparent belief that the manufacturer chose the cheap route to relieve pressure made your question seem more like a rant than a desire for information.

Comment: I could not agree more with the previous comment by zenbike. Sometimes the right answer is "don't do that". What the OP is planning to do is plainly WRONG. Or, at least, should be done by his own risk. I'm afraid no one can provide approppriate help about this modification, here in Bicycle Exchange since "it makes no sense", really.

Comment: final thought: this reaction you are getting is very, very uncommon around here. This is a very very supportive community. And it is not trolling, on the contrary, is the intention to help you. When reactions like this happen, it might be the time to reconsider ourselves, too.

Comment: As I said before, sometimes, the right answer is don't do that. It's like if someone asks the right way to jump off a bridge without hurting themselves. You have 3 choices. 1. Ignore them. 2. Try to tell them how to jump "carefully". Or 3. Tell them that it isn't and can't be safe. I choose 3. Because it is the best way to be helpful and supportive.

Comment: @macias Actually, it happens quite a lot here, and it use to be very helpful. The very nature of Stack Exchange is this, like you can read (if you want) here (this blog is written by Stack Exchange staff): http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html